# unable to startactivity componentinfo

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I'm having a error when i pressed a button form mainactivity it will go to an activity but instead it crash..... i have never encountered this error before could you guys help me out

```
Process: com.sp.ez_mart, PID: 9514
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sp.ez_mart/com.sp.ez_mart.navigation_front}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040031
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040031
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:207)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1120)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.sp.ez_mart.navigation_front.onCreate(navigation_front.java:37)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6754)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Application terminated.

here is the java where the error is coming from

```
public class navigation_front extends AppCompatActivity {
Button scan_btn;
Spinner dest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_front);
    scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    final Activity activity = this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Please Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
    dest = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_destination);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.destination_array, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dest.setAdapter(adapter);
    dest.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.destination_array);
            String type = dataArray[position];
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_current);
    final Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_destination);
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navigate);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(navigation_front.this, NavigateImage.class);

            if (edit.getText().toString().trim().equals("Entrance") && spin.getSelectedItem().equals("Vegetables")) {
                i.putExtra("image", R.drawable.entrance_vege);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (edit.getText().toString().trim().equals("Entrance") && spin.getSelectedItem().equals("Canned-Food")) {
                i.putExtra("image", R.drawable.entrance_can);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Valid Value.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result.getContents() != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_current);
            editText.setText("" + result.getContents(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
```

here is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"></LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="Current Location :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Edit_current"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    tools:backgroundTint="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
    android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
    android:layout_weight="0.21"
    android:hint="Scan/Type Location"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.14"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="115dp">

    <Button
        android:text="Scan Nearest Qr Code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scan_btn"
        android:background="@color/zxing_possible_result_points"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="224dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="Destination :"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Destination"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/edit_destination" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="174dp">

        <Button
            android:text="Navigate Me!"
            android:id="@+id/navigate"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout
```

new error

```
    Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:3 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: Seems like your navigation_front xml file is causing the error. Check whether all the resources used inside the xml are defined in your application or not.

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException` show xml

Comment: @Jason what happened.? solved it or not.???

Comment: nope still same error

Comment: IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
Here Use (this). and Remove your additional line.final Activity activity = this;
i know both are same but try it.

Comment: @Jason, see my code and apply. One done clear the app `Sync project with gradle file`, hope this will help u

Comment: wait lol i just retype and it worked lol the setcontentview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you missed Layout tag. Use proper layout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_front); //<---here 
        ........
         .........
```

And align code properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"></LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="Current Location :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Edit_current"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    tools:backgroundTint="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
    android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
    android:layout_weight="0.21"
    android:hint="Scan/Type Location"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.14"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="115dp">

    <Button
        android:text="Scan Nearest Qr Code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scan_btn"
        android:background="@color/zxing_possible_result_points"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="224dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"></LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="Destination :"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Destination"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit_destination" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="174dp">

    <Button
        android:text="Navigate Me!"
        android:id="@+id/navigate"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Replace this :

```
setContentView(navigation_front);
```

With :

```
setContentView(R.layout.navigation_front);
```

Here you forgot to Add **R.layout**..Thats why you get the Error **ResourceNotFound**

Hope this will helps..(:

Comment: still giving same erroe